# A flux query to be used as a grafana variable which will return all keys in a particular measurement from Influx Cloud

Tags: grafana, influxdb, flux, flux-influxdb

I want to get all keys for a particular measurement from a particular bucket to use in a variable on a Grafana dashboard.

I'm fairly certain that I'm starting correctly:

```
from(bucket: "my_bucket")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "host")
```

How do you get a list of the keys from the measurement `host`?

I've tried adding:

```
|> keys()
and
|> columns() 
|> keep(columns: ["_value"]) 
|> group() 
|> distinct()
```

I suspect it might involve:

```
|> schema.tagKeys()
```

But I can't import schema in flux cloud data explorer.

I know it must be something simple, but I can't find the answer in documentation or searches on here.

EDIT: Didn't realise this, but host contains float and string values.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty new to flux query, but I found you can get unique keys from a column (in this case 'site') using the following.

```
from(bucket: "my_bucket")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "host")
  |> group(columns: ["site"])
  |> unique(column: "site")
  |> sort(columns: ["site"], desc: false)
```

Comment: Because "host" included float as well as string, this didn't work for me. This isn't your fault, as I didn't include this in the brief above (I didn't realise it myself!). But I suspect that if my data had been as initially described, this would have worked, so plus 1!